# How do exponential numbers work in C

Tags: c

The output of the below code using exponential numbers is 1.#INF00 -33.000000 0.000000. How?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float p=3.5e38f;
    float n=-3.3e1f;
    float m=1.0e-38f;
    printf("%f %f %f",p,n,m);
}
```

Comment: Do some reading on the limits of single precision floats before handing in your homework.

Comment: You basically hit the limits of single-precision floating point numbers. That's why you got "Infinity" and "Zero" as outputs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 0):

You really need to learn the basics.  A Google search for "how do floating point numbers work" would be a good start.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Briefly, the first number overflows to "infinity" (INF).  The second one is 3.3 times 10 raised to the power of 1.  The third underflows to zero.